Calculating Second to Max Date without >1 FIXED LOD
I'm working on a calculation for "Second to Max Date" in order to compare the Max Date (as a most recent forecast) to the Second to Max Date (as the second to most recent forecast).
I'm interested in avoiding using more than one FIXED statement for performance reasons on the server as content is replicated to clients, as there is a hunch that nesting FIXED LOD is causing Tableau server crashes for our team.
The current setup is as follows:
Exclude Max Date = IF [Forecast Date] != { FIXED : MAX([Forecast Date]) } THEN [Forecast Date] END
Second to Max Date = { FIXED : MAX(IF [Forecast Date] != { FIXED : MAX([Forecast Date]) } THEN [Forecast Date] END) }
In this case, the results produced are as expected. Forecasts do not occur at regular intervals so we cannot simply subtract a number of months from the original Max Date. However, we are looking for an alternative that does NOT use two FIXED LOD.
The value must satisfy the condition of being able to be set as a "Value when workbook opens" within a parameter "Comparison Date" that holds Forecast Date values, noting the default set value will then be the Second to Max Date.
We cannot use table calculations as they are unable to feed the default parameter "Value when workbook opens" (at least to my knowledge).
Any assistance or insight as to whether an alternative is possible is appreciated. Thank you!

If the only thing you want is an efficient way to find and display the two most recent dates in a datasource, you can do that easily with a Top N filter and using the MIN() and MAX() functions. See the screenshot below.

If you want to do more with the info that just display it, say you need to use those dates in subsequent calculations, then you can either use LOD calcs as you've found - or you could write a small scrap of custom SQL, similar to what would feed the viz above. You then can include that custom SQL result in the data model for your data source.
Depending on the database, the SQL would look something like
select
  min(Date) as "second recent date",
  max(Date) as "most recent date"
from
  (select Date from DataSource order by Date desc limit 2) 

Most of the time, I advise against using custom SQL with Tableau, and instead recommend learning to use the corresponding Tableau features - letting Tableau generate the SQL. That is most often a more efficient and flexible approach, but this is an example of a situation where custom SQL can be useful.
